Seeking Advice on Requesting Professor's Help for Internship Opportunities
I'm currently an undergraduate student in a condensed matter physics research group at a mid-tier college, actively seeking internship opportunities. Despite having interviewed with a notable company, I wasn't successful, and I'm reflecting on whether my college affiliation may have influenced the outcome.
My professor, with a strong academic background including a PhD and postdoc from prestigious institutions, has connections with researchers at these institutions. While I'm currently working with him for this summer, I'm also considering asking for his recommendation to potentially join his previous groups or connections there for programs like REUs in future semesters.
Previously, I casually mentioned to him, "If you have any suggestions or know someone, please let me know," but his efforts in assisting me seemed minimal, possibly assuming I only needed passive support.
I'm now contemplating seeking more active assistance from him in securing internship opportunities. However, I'm unsure about the appropriateness of this and how best to approach the conversation.
Could anyone offer advice on whether it's appropriate to seek more active assistance from my professor and, if so, how I should go about doing this?

Internships for this summer are likely thin on the ground at this point. For my national lab the last date to hire on a summer intern posting was last month. Next time around start early and search broadly. And, yes, actively engage with your professors.

Yeah, that's what I figured. I wanted the post to be general, not really aimed at particular semesters. Thanks for the advice!
